# Почему не работает приложение, через прямую установку apk файла на смартфоне

Tags: android, android-sdk

При запуске программы через Android Studio, **приложение устанавливается и работает.**

Если пытаюсь перенести app-debug.apk на смартфон и установить через стандартную "Программу установки пакетов", установка проходит нормально, но при запуске приложения вылетает ошибка **"В приложении "APP" произошла ошибка".**

В файле AndroidManifest.xml добавил всевозможные разрешения:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.input"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.display"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.GeomagneticField"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.Sensor"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.SensorEvent"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>



<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.permission.ACCOUNT" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
```

Лог:

```
04-23 23:39:16.384 21954-21954/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-23 23:39:17.661 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ru.startandroid.randomcrane-1/lib/arm64
04-23 23:39:17.676 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-23 23:39:17.686 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = ru.startandroid.randomcrane
04-23 23:39:17.688 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
04-23 23:39:17.690 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 23:39:17.714 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: ru.startandroid.randomcrane, PID: 21954
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.startandroid.randomcrane/ru.startandroid.randomcrane.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ru.startandroid.randomcrane.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.startandroid.randomcrane-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.startandroid.randomcrane-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ru.startandroid.randomcrane.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.startandroid.randomcrane-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.startandroid.randomcrane-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.startandroid.randomcrane.MainActivity
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                        ... 12 more
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
04-23 23:39:21.292 21954-21954/ru.startandroid.randomcrane I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21954 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Без логов мы вам помочь не сможем. Никак.

Comment: Подскажите тогда, пожалуйста, как собрать логи в этом случае

Comment: Самый простой способ - подключить к компу, открыть студию (т.е. всё как обычно при обычной установке через студию) и установить апк не из студии - логи будут как обычно в консоли студии

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, добавил логи к вопросу. Я так понимаю, он не видит класс MainActivity. Но класс описан в файле MainActivity.java. В чем тут проблема?

Comment: А где находится `MainActivity.java`? Дело не в том, что он не описан в манифесте, как раз с этим все хорошо. Вылет происходит потому что нет его там где он должен быть. Какой у него `package`?

Comment: package ru.startandroid.randomcrane;

Comment: фактически находится: C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\RandomCrane\app\src\main\java\ru\startandroid\randomcrane

Comment: @Данила, попробуйте `InstantRun` отклчить. Также попробуйте `build-clean` `build-rebuild` и `File-Invalidate cache and Restart`. Помочь может даже ребут компа

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо помогло! В чём конкретно была проблема не подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `InstantRun` отклчить. Также попробуйте `build-clean`, `build-rebuild` и `File-Invalidate cache and Restart`. Помочь может даже `ребут компа`.

Все эти манипуляции могут решить проблему сборки приложения с использование кэша студии. Бывает, что код изменился в редакторе, но не в кэше сборщика и, из-за различных механизмов обновления приложения из студии на девайсе и полной сборки apk изменения в коде не попадают в `apk` файл